# Includes not found in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, include-path

I have been working on this makefile for quite some time now and I can't find the solution to my problem. Here is the makefile:

```
# Compiler:
CPPFLAGS = $(OPT_FLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(STANDARD_FLAGS) \
           $(WARN_AS_ERRORS_FLAGS)

# Source files, headers, etc.:
OBJ_DIR      = $(CX_BUILD_ROOT)/tests/unit
OUT_DIR      = $(CX_BUILD_ROOT)/tests/unit
INCLUDES     = -I$(CX_SRC_ROOT)/cXbase/publicAPI
LIBINCLUDES  = -L$(CX_BUILD_ROOT)/connectx/libs
VPATH        = tests

SRCS      = cxUnitTests.cpp\
            test_Player.cpp\
            test_Name.cpp\
            test_Game.cpp\
            test_GameBoard.cpp\
            test_Disc.cpp\
            test_Color.cpp\
            test_AsciiColorCode.cpp\

OBJS      = test_Player.o\
            test_Name.o\
            test_Game.o\
            test_GameBoard.o\
            test_Disc.o\
            test_Color.o\
            test_AsciiColorCode.o\

LIBS      = -lgtest\
            -lgtest_main\
            -lpthread\
            -lcXbase

# Product:
MAIN = cxUnitTests.out


all: make_dir $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    @echo Invoquing GCC...
    $(CPPC) $(LIBINCLUDES) -o $(OUT_DIR)/$(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo $(MAIN) has been compiled and linked!

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo Invoquing GCC...
    $(CPPC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
    @echo Object files created!

make_dir:
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)

clean:
    @echo Removing object files...
    $(RM) $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o
    @echo Object files removed!

mrproper: clean
    @echo Cleaning project...
    $(RM) $(OUT_DIR)/$(MAIN)
    @echo Project cleaned!

depend: $(SRCS)
    @echo Finding dependencies...
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^
    @echo Dependencies found!
```

All values in the "Source files, headers, etc" section are defined in other makefiles from which this makefile is invoked with the `$(MAKE) -C` option They can all be `@echo`ed and the resultant values are good. When I run `make`, I get:

`g++   -g3 -std=c++0x -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion  -c -o test_Player.o tests/test_Player.cpp`

and

`tests/test_Player.cpp:36:30: fatal error: publicAPI/Player.h: No such file or directory`

It seems that `make` cannot access the content of the `INCLUDES` variable for some reason. I use Gnu-make.

Can you see what is wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make is using its built-in rule for compiling C++ files because your pattern rule `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp` doesn't match your list of objects. By coincidence you've used one of the variables that the built-in recipe uses (`CPPFLAGS`), but make makes no use of `INCLUDES`.

One way to fix it would be to put something like the following after your list of objects

```
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(OBJS))
```

Comment: Your solution works and is more elegant. I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. In fact, there were two:

1. The `INCLUDES` variable should have been set to
   `$(CX_SRC_ROOT)/cXbase` instead of `$(CX_SRC_ROOT)/cXbase/publicAPI`
   since, like the error message shows, the include file for `Player`
   is looked for in `publicAPI/Player.h` so `publicAPI` was there
   twice, but didn't show twice in the `@echo`.
2. My object list should have been in the form: `$(OBJ_DIR)/objectFile.o`.